# how to merge more than one list into only one list? dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, merge

i have a

```
class shop {
int id;
String name;
List<Product> products;
}

class Product {
int id;
String productName;
}
```

where each shop has his own products , how to merge all shops products in one list
how to create a List of all products

Comment: what is your input data? how can you assign a product to shop? i am assuming that `Product.id` is "product ID" and not "ID of shop that product belongs to"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply merge `Lists` with `+` operator:

```
List<Product> list1 = ...;
List<Product> list2 = ...;
List<Product> list3 = ...;

List<Product> mergedList = list1 + list2 + list3;
```

Also, `Dart 2.3` and higher supports spread operator, which can be used as follows:

```
List<Product> mergedList2 = [...list1, ...list2, ...list3];
```

For dynamic number of shops you can use basic forEach:

```
List<Shop> shops = ...;

List<Product> mergedList = List();

shops.forEach((shop) => mergedList.addAll(shop.products));
```

Comment: okay but i have a dynamic number of shops not constant is there a way to loop on List<Shop> shops and create the all products List ?

Comment: @ialyzaafan did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge lists using **+** or the **spread operator**

Using the **Addition Operator:**

```
List<shop> shops = [shop1, shop2];
List<Product> products = shop1.products + shop2.products;
```

Using **Spread Operator:**

```
List<Product> products = [...shop1.products, ...shop2.products];
```

**Edit**

You would need to do it like this:

```
List<shop> shops = [shop1, shop2,...];
List<Product> mergedProducts = []
for(int i = 0; i < shops.length; i++){
    mergedProducts = mergedProducts + shops[i].products;
}
```

Comment: okay but i have a dynamic number of shops not constant is there a way to loop on List<Shop> shops and create the all products List ?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it correct so that other people who might have the same problem can see it!

Comment: The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void

Comment: To help you further, I would have to see your code!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `fold` function. You can do it in 1 line.

```
List<Shop> shops = [shop1, shop2, shop3];

List<Product> allProducts = shops.fold<List<Product>>([], (productList, shop) => productList..addAll(shop.products));
```